# Completeness and Context-Sensitive Languages.

Tags: np-hardness, fl.formal-languages, space-bounded

I'm interested in two questions regarding [context-sensitive languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_language) (CSL) and completeness:

1. Is there a notion of completeness for CSL, and which languages are complete?
2. Are there natural CSL that are NP-complete?

For 2., I can certainly think of natural NP-complete languages that are CSL (as CSL is equal to NSPACE[$n$], SAT is a CSL), but I'm searching for the other way around, i.e., a context-sensitive *grammar* describing an NP-complete language.

Comment: Let's see if I understand (2) correctly: Would it be sufficient to write a context-sensitive grammar that generates all valid 3SAT instances over a fixed alphabet of connectives and SAT variables?

Comment: Well, I would not have added SAT variables as part of the alphabet (a binary encoding of their indices is good enough), but that would certainly answer my second point!

Comment: By the way, did you give it a try?

Comment: (1) As you mentioned, it is possible to write down a CSG for 3SAT, but that sounds similar to writing down a complete description of a Turing machine for the maximum-flow problem (or any specific language in P); I would not expect that it will give any insight on complexity theory.  (But hey, if it turns out otherwise, I will be happy to hear it.)  (2) Generally, the notion of context-sensitive grammars and the notion of NP-completeness do not go well together because the set of context-sensitive languages is not closed under polynomial-time reductions.

Comment: Thanks for that comment Tsuyoshi.  Indeed, a grammar for 3SAT is probably not what I'm searching for, but I went with the same reaction as yours: if it is somewhat easy/natural, I'd be interested.  For your (2), one of my aim is the following: say I have a class of CS languages closed by logspace-reduction, and I want to show that my class does not (or is unlikely to) contain NP-complete problems, I would only have to show that the specific NP-complete CS language is not in my class, which could be easier if the language is naturally CS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer your first question, a reducibility fitting your needs is log-lin-reducibility, which is logspace reducibility with the additional constraint that the size of the output string of the reduction is at most linear in the size of the input. If I remember correctly, the membership problem for context-sensitive grammars (or, if you like, linearly bounded automata) is the canonical CSL-complete problem w.r.t. log-lin reducibility.

On the applied side, the universality problem of (ordinary) regular expressions over binary alphabet, is CSL-complete w.r.t. log-lin-reducibility. The notion and the completeness result are found in  Albert R. Meyer and Larry J. Stockmeyer (SWAT 1972) also: Stockmeyer (PhD thesis, MIT 1974). For further background and similar results in that area, see also the recent survey by Holzer and Kutrib (DLT 2010).

**EDIT (2017/03/06):** Regarding your second question, the accepted answer to the question below cites a paper by Rounds (1973), which constructs a one-way nested stack automaton recognizing SAT. While SAT will not qualify as a "natural" CSL, it might be worth to search the literature for other examples of one-way nested stack automata or indexed grammars.

[Context-sensitive grammar for SAT?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9982/context-sensitive-grammar-for-sat)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is indeed what I was searching for!

Comment: For the edit: Fantastic!  Thanks for getting back there and completing this answer, this is great spirit!