# Decidability of "does this CFG define a regular language"

Tags: reference-request, fl.formal-languages

Is the decidablity of the following question known?

*Given a CFG* G, *is* L(G) *regular?*

I've seen a bunch of decidability results in the world of CFLs, but I don't think I've ever seen this one, and can't find anything about it.

Comment: See Hopcroft and Ullman, 1979, page 281.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Being_in_a_lower_level_of_the_Chomsky_hierarchy) it is undecidable.

Comment: Fair enough; I guess I only looked at the page for CFLs and not CFGs. Still, the page you cite doesn't give any references for that claim, and even a more directed search in Sipser (using the sections in the "further reading" citations and a better index term) doesn't yield anything. Closest it has is "does this *TM* define a regular language", which falls right out of Rice's thm.

Comment: It's a consequence of Greibach's Theorem, see last pages here: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/gbooks/PCPh04.pdf

Comment: I found a reference to include in the Wikipedia article. (The source Shir posted looks better than the one I found, in the sense that it justifies the claim of undecidability rather than just stating it, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be published yet.)

Comment: If the alphabet is unary it is decidable. ;)

Comment: @David, see my comment below the question for a published reference.

Comment: Is the "regularity" of a context-free grammar recognizable or co-recognizable?